# How to order by transaction date in an accounting table with transactions having the same date

Tags: mysql, database, accounting

I am designing an accounting database using mysql and I have to order the transactions by date column **txn_date**. The problem is the ordering of transactions falling in the same date.

1. I have come up with two solutions -  Make the txn_date column as
   timestamp, user only inputs the date, so the application will
   automatically get the current time and append it to the date.
2. Keep a txn_date as date only and add another column integer sl_no which
   will increment as transactions with same date are inserted into the
   table.

solution 1

```
create table journal (
        id int,
        txn_date timestamp
    )
```

solution 2

```
create table journal (
    id int,
    txn_date date,
    sl_no int
)
```

both of the solutions work at the moment, I am wondering which is the "correct" design. Input from people who have worked on accounting softwares will be much appreciated.

Comment: What are the ramifications should you not be able to determine which transaction happened first?

Comment: You may need to backdate or forward date transactions so using current date may not be an option.Quite often you would need a booking date (ie when it happened) and a transaction date(when it affects the account from) and they may be the same or may not be. Also holding an independent txn serial number is helpful (an auto_increment id migh be useful)

Comment: I have to generate a running balance dynamically for every transaction (like we see in bank statements), and hence correct ordering of transactions by date and time is required.

Comment: In a banking system a booking date may be when the transaction happened and the txn date may be from when interest is charged. Also you may need to provide contra txn ability which exactly reverses the effect of another txn - at another point in time.